# Prove that every continuous mapping between $\omega$-complete partially ordered sets is monotone.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I'm a physicist trying to understand rigorous proofs in the very basics of category theory and I'm having difficulties seeing things that perhaps are trivial but just can't see them, so I need some help, can you help me with this?

> Prove that every continuous mapping between $\omega$-complete partially
>   ordered sets is monotone.

Thank you!

P.S. Definitions: A poset $(X;\le)$ is $\omega$-complete if every monotone sequence (or chain) of $X$ has a supremum. A function $f:X\to Y$ between $\omega$-complete posets is continuous if, each time that $s$ is the supremum of a chain $C=(c_{n})_{n\in\Bbb N}$ in $X$, $f(s)$ is the supremum of the image of $C$ under $f$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $(c_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a chain then I denote with $\bigvee_n c_n$ its supremum which exists by assumption.

Suppose $a \leq b$. Let $$ c_n = \begin{cases} a & \text{ if } n = 0\\ b & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}.$$

Then $c_n$ is a chain with supremum $b$. Thus

$$f(b) = f\left(\bigvee_n c_n\right) = \bigvee_n f(c_n) \geq f(a)$$
where the last relation follows from the fact that $c_0 = a$.

Thus $a \leq b$ implies $f(a) \leq f(b)$ as required.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but can you tell what does the "$\bigvee_n$" mean?

Comment: $\bigvee_n$ is the supremum